# How to implement dropdown with hundreds of options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a website where users have to enter some of their information. One piece of information is their college major. I don't want them t type it out (I have a good reason why it can't be typed out). So in the form, when I have like three options, I do this:

```
<%= f.input :option, collection: ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"], required: true, label: 'Options' %>
```

I can do the above method for the majors as well, but it will clutter up the code. Since there are more than 150 majors I want to include, is there a different easy way I can do this without cluttering up the code for my views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest approach would be using constant. Create `constants.rb` file in config/initializers, and place there something like this:

```
MAJORS = ["option 1",
          "option 2"]
```

Then, select call in view would look like this:

```
 <%= f.input :option, collection: MAJORS, required: true, label: 'Options' %>
```

You may also consider making MAJORS a model, and store all the fields in database. Also, picking up from that list may be a problem, consider using [typeahead](https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails) gem to make it easier for users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'll probably go with the constants.rb method

Comment: Global constants are never a good idea and a constants.rb will likely encourage this.  There should be a model that MAJORS constant should fit into such as a Student model or something.  Nest it in there.